# Creating Fully-Transparent Shapes in Electron BrowserWindow (A "Cut-Out" Window)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, winapi, electron

I'd like to create a `browserWindow` that has a cutout (or hole) in it.

I'm looking to create something similar to this:

[image: https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/holes/holes.gif]

Essentially, it is a window that contains a fully-transparent shape inside of it, while the rest of the entire application remains unaffected.
I've heard of some ways of doing this using the Win32 API in applications programmed in C# or C++ using `SetWindowRgn`. Is this also possible in Electron?


Here is a code snippet of a tutorial I [found](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291/Creating-Holes-in-a-Window) online in C++ demonstrating what I'm looking to do in Electron:

```
void CHolesDlg::CreateHole(CRgn& rgn)
{
    CRgn WindowRgn;
    CRgn HoleRgn;
    static CRgn ThisRgn;

    CRect WindowRect;
    static bool Start = true;
    GetWindowRect (WindowRect);   // Get the Window rect
    WindowRgn.CreateRectRgn (0,0,WindowRect.Width (), WindowRect.Height());

    // initialize the hole region
    HoleRgn.CreateRectRgn (0,0,0,0);
 
    if (Start)
    {
       // initialize ThisRgn
       ThisRgn.CreateRectRgn (0,0,0,0);
       // First copy the region himself in ThisRgn
       ThisRgn.CopyRgn (&rgn);
    }
    else
    {
       // Other times, Add the new region to ThisRgn
       ThisRgn.CombineRgn (&ThisRgn, &rgn, RGN_OR);
    }
 
    Start = false;
    // create the border of the hole(s) with ThisRgn and set it in that
    // border by reversing it
    HoleRgn.CombineRgn (&ThisRgn, &WindowRgn, RGN_XOR);
    SetWindowRgn ((HRGN__*)HoleRgn.m_hObject, TRUE);
}

void CMyControl::ClearHoles()
{
    CRect WindowRect;
    CRgn WindowRgn;
    GetWindowRect (WindowRect);
    WindowRgn.CreateRectRgn (0,0,WindowRect.Width (), WindowRect.Height());
    // Get back to the classic border
    SetWindowRgn ((HRGN__*)WindowRgn.m_hObject, TRUE);
}

void CMyControl::OnClear()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CString s;
    GetDlgItem (IDC_CLEAR)->GetWindowText (s);
    if (s == "Clear Holes")
    {
       GetDlgItem (IDC_CLEAR)->SetWindowText ("Show Holes");
       ClearHoles();
    }

    if (s == "Show Holes")
    {
       GetDlgItem (IDC_CLEAR)->SetWindowText ("Clear Holes");
       ShowHoles();
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to do this? I am using Electron with NodeJS.

Many thanks for any suggestions or replies in advance.

**EDIT [2/10/2022]:** I am not looking to create the entire `browserWindow` transparent, only a small portion of it, while the rest of the window remains unaffected (see above image as an example of what I am looking for).

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, it was not *normally* possible. Your best bet would be to create a transparent, frameless window but the transparent area would still not be clickable.

**However**, there does seem to be a trick with triggering mouse events to sort of emulate click-through transparency. I am not sure how well it works in different operating systems though but you can go ahead and check the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1335), where it's been discussed.

I myself did not read it in detail, just went through it quickly before posting my answer.

As for making your window transparent, it's as simple as this:

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron');

let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800, 
    height: 600,
    transparent: true,
    frame: false
});

win.show();
```

Comment: @Joe You don't have to make it fully transparent though. You can still use html and css backgrounds to make it as you wish.

Comment: Already tried that. Did not work well. A fully transparent DIV on a solid color BODY gives the solid color of the BODY and not the full-transparency of the `browserWindow`